# Why Can't I Pull Google Artifact Registry Docker Images Build with Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam, google-artifact-registry

I created a Docker image (`$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME`) using Google Cloud Build (GCB).  I don't seem to be able to `pull` `$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME`:

```shell
docker pull us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/. . ./$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG

#=>

Error response from daemon: Get https://us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/. . ./$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME/v1: denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts"denied on resource "projects/. . ./$DOCKER_REPOSITORY_NAME" (or it may not exist)
```

How can I `pull` `$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME`?

Comment: Have you logged in to docker before pulling?

Comment: Hi, yes, I wasn't logged in so I did and still the same Error response.

Comment: Are you authenticated with gcloud? If so, change your docker authentication like this `gcloud auth configure-docker -q`, and tell me if it's better. In addition, check the spelling of your registry/image with the gcloud command, example like this `gcloud beta artifacts repositories list`

Comment: Perfect, I was able to pull and push from the registry as soon as  ran the command.

Answer (score 4):

The error message seems to indicate that you need to grant permissions.

You will need to run the `add-iam-policy-binding` command:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
--member=$MEMBER \
--role=$ROLE
```

where `$ROLE` is `artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts`.

See [this](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#grant) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add role related to Artifact to your service account. Even if your service account has a owner role it wont work because GCP artifact repo has its own permissions boundary.

Comment: You would only need to associate a role with a service account (`$SERVICE_ACCOUNT`) if you are impersonating `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT` when `pull`ing or `push`ing a Docker image from or to GAR.  Posting an answer that involves impersonating `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT` would help someone who reaches this page in search of your answer, but only if you provide more supporting details and step-by-step instructions for associating a role (e.g.,`artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts`) with `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT`  using the Cloud SDK (`gcloud`), the console and/or the REST API.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the setup instructions from artifact registry at a later time (migrated from container registry) and it's needd to specify the region `gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev`